# how to update query in sqlite3 with variable in python?

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm trying to update query with variable, first I wrote a searching def to find the exact person then I want to update its information(for example his/her national ID depends on what variable the user entered). I also want to use the same method for deleting, first find the right person and then delete it. I want to know how to do it.
Thanks in advance.

def searching():

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('./Person_list.db')

while (True):

    Category_ = input("Depending on which Category you want to search for the person you are looking for: (National_ID, firstName, lastName, Gender, fatherName) "
    )
    Value_ = input("Please write your desire " + Category_
    )

    cursor = conn.execute("SELECT National_ID, firstName, lastName, Gender, fatherName from Person_list where Category_ = " + Value_)
    cursor = list(cursor)

    for row in cursor:
        print("National_ID = ", row[0])
        print("firstName = ", row[1])
        print("lastName = ", row[2])
        print("Gender = ", row[3])
        print("fatherName = ", row[4], "\n")

    if len(list(cursor)) == 1:
        print("He/She is the person you are looking for: ")

        return list(cursor)

        break

conn.close()
```

## updating the list:

def updating():

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('./Person_list.db')

searching_ = searching()

conn.execute("UPDATE Person_list set Naotional_ID = ? where Naotional_ID = searching_[0] ",(National_ID, firstName, lastName, Gender, fatherName) )
conn.commit()

print ("The person Information Updated")

conn.close()
```

Comment: Hey Pedram, any `?` inside the query will be replaced, in order, by values in the tuple: `conn.execute("UPDATE Person_list set Naotional_ID = ? where Naotional_ID = ?", (National_ID, searching[0]))`

Comment: Please read https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.execute

Comment: Thanks, Is there any way to ask the user (with input() for instance) which category he/she wants to change and then ask its value and put them in the update? for example, he/she wants to change the national ID or any other category and then type its correct value. so that specific information gets changed for that particular person.